# Telegram bot Nested previous button,node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

How Can I Back from 3th Level node to Secend level node after That to First Level node? My Problem is `Back` Name, Because That is Same,,,
**This is my Code:**

```
    bot.onText(/\/start/, function onLoveText(msg) {
      const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          keyboard: StartKeyboard,
          resize_keyboard:true,
          one_time_keyboard: true
        })
      };
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Hello', opts);
    });
 bot.onText(/\Back/, function onLoveText(msg) {
      const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          keyboard: StartKeyboard,
          resize_keyboard:true,
          one_time_keyboard: true
        })
      };
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Hello', opts);
    });
 bot.onText(/\Back/, function onLoveText(msg) {  //  I Can't Use Backkk
      const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          keyboard: BackKeyboard,
          resize_keyboard:true,
          one_time_keyboard: true
        })
      };
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Hello', opts);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: i writed my code here.

Comment: i'm sorry, im new here. i deleted and put in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved With `callback_query` and `Inline Keyboards`

```
const helpKeyboard = [[{
    text: `back`,
    callback_data: `back3`
}]]



bot.on('callback_query', msg => {
 if (msg.data == `back3`) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you probably should do is save the state, the user is currently in using his unique id.

I don't have experience using nodejs for telegram bots, so the following code is kind of pseudo.

```
userStateMap = {};

switch ($chat.text)
{
    case "/start":
          sendWelcomeMessage($chat);
          userStateMap[$chat.id] = 0; // save the state
          break;
    case "1":
          $chat.text = "you clicked 1";
          $chat.reply_markup = getCustomKeyboard();
          return sendMessage($chat);
          userStateMap[$chat.id] = 1; // save the state
          break;
    case "about":
          $chat.text = "you clicked about";
          $chat.reply_markup = getCustomKeyboard();
          return sendMessage($chat);
          userStateMap[$chat.id] = 4; // save the state
          break;
    case "2":
          $chat.text = "you clicked 2";
          $chat.reply_markup = getCustomKeyboard2();
          return sendMessage($chat);
          userStateMap[$chat.id] = 2; // save the state
          break;
    case "previous":
          $chat.text = "you clicked previous";
          $chat.reply_markup = getCustomKeyboard(userStateMap[$chat.id]); // use the saved state
          return sendMessage($chat);
          break;
    case "3":
          $chat.text = "you clicked 3";
          $chat.reply_markup = getCustomKeyboard3();
          return sendMessage($chat);
          userStateMap[$chat.id] = 3; // save the state
          break;
}

//customize getCustomKeyboard to receive the state and use it to calculate the next keyboard
```

So you would update the state after each request, and for requests like `previous` you would calculate the needed keyboard depending on the last saved state.

Comment: What RegExp?
Do you still need help with this one? Just update your question with the newest code and problem.

Comment: i updated my question code, someone said me use this code, with this modules. `node-telegram-bot-api`, but i couldn't understand very well